# Unity, Coroutine acts different on Android

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, coroutine

Next code below acts different on Android, while in Editor it acts as supposed:

```
 private IEnumerator CountTo(int target)
 {
     yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.5f);

     int start = 0;

     do
     {
         ScoreText.text = string.Format(scoreText, start);

         if (start != 0)
         {
             SoundManager.instance.Play(ScoreSound, default, 0.4f);
         }

         start++;

         yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.33f);
     }
     while (start <= target);
 }
```

In editor, when it called, it waits for 0.5 seconds before launch (to wait Complete level sound to play), counts to `target` one by one with playing `ScoreSound` each time (except the first one) when score changes.

On Android it firsts plays all of the the needed `ScoreSound` sounds and only then, SLOWLY (almost like with lags) changes the UI score. In debugger, step by step, everything works fine. Using the Profiler, FPS is stable when this happens.

Any idea what can be causing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please provide us with some more context? Where and how are you calling this method? What is the value of `target`? What happens if `target` is <= 0? What is the value of `scoreText`? What is the `default` parameter that you are passing to the `Play()` method? Are you certain that you are not starting this coroutine more than once?

Comment: If everything directly controlled by this coroutine works properly I'd look outside it, like what's in scoreText? Does that change over time? Starting the coroutine more than once is another good thing to check as suggested by @DarrenRuane If I had a dollar for every bug I've fixed due to that... :)

Comment: `target` can only be [0, 3]. This coroutine starts when the level is completed. `ScoreText` is a TextMeshProUGUI, which displays score in the UI. `Play(AudioClip clip, float pitch, float volume)`. Yes, I am ABSOLUTELY sure that coroutine starts only once. Ok, I'll try to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, guys, sorry, I figured it out, the answer is actually really stupid... So it turns out that this was happening because of the Post Processing Stack's Depth of Field, it was activated during Level Complete phase and when the `CountTo` was called, so it seems that these two somehow interfered each other, so I've got what I've got.

Sorry again! Thanks!